# How to avoid "unable to read memory"

Tags: c++

I have a struct:

```
struct a {
   a(){};
   a(int one,int two): a(one),b(two){};
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}

a * b;
cout << b->c;
```

And sometimes when i want to read (for ex.) `c` and in debbuger this value is called

> 'unable to read memory'

Then my program crashed.

And now, how to check that value is readable or not ?

Best Regards.

Comment: You avoid this by allocating the memory. All you have now is an uninitialized pointer pointing to a garbage memory location. But really theres no reason to use dynamic allocation in the example you've shown.

Comment: I know that i should allocate memory. But this is EXAMPLE. `if(b->c == NULL)` dont work too.

Comment: @ThomasAndrees, that example doesn't allocate memory either.

Comment: @ThomasAndrees It wouldn't be null (most of the time anyway), I said it points to garbage. Its unitialized therefore has a random value.

Comment: @ThomasAndrees: `b` is uninitialized, therefore dereferencing it (e.g., using `->`) is undefined behavior. Kaboom, if you're lucky. If you initialized your pointer (`a* b = nullptr;`) you can check if it's null later on.

Comment: I know that `b` is unitalized i know it in this code ... BUT the question is "HOW to check that if i won't know? - With some if instruction."

Comment: @ThomasAndrees You cant. Its your job to make sure it either points to NULL *or* a valid memory location.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't initialised the pointer to point to anything, so it's invalid. You can't, in general, test whether a pointer points to a valid object. It's up to you to make sure it does; for example:

```
a obj(1,2);    // an object
a * b = &obj;  // a pointer, pointing to obj;
cout << b->a;  // OK: b points to a valid object
```

You can make a pointer *null* if you don't want it to point to anything. You mustn't dereference it, but it is possible to test for a null pointer:

```
a * b = nullptr;     // or 0, in ancient dialects
if (b) cout << b->a; // OK: test prevents dereferencing
cout << b->a;        // ERROR: b is null
```

But beware that this doesn't help in situations where a pointer might be invalid but not null; perhaps because it wasn't initialised, or because it pointed to an object that has been destroyed.

In general, avoid pointers except when you actually need them; and be careful not to use invalid pointers when you do. If you just want an object, then just use an object:

```
a b(1,2);     // an object
cout << b.a;  // OK: b is a valid object
```

Comment: The second example is the answer for my question. 
- When i initalize struct i should set pointer for nullptr; (i thought that is make by default) 

THANK YOU.